# Finding a Structured Way to Learn Dynamic Programming

Tags: codeigniter, dynamic-programming, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, programmers-notepad

I started to learn dynamic programming... but was stuck on how to structrally learn ... I  want to effective learning process with in a month I want to learn the dp with practice how I start and what is the best source and what wat to learn dp I think no one can answer this his type of question but still, I have hope waiting for the worthy reply

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean [Dynamic Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming) or [Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) ?